# Auto Paging in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

newbie in wp8 development

say I have a long paragraph, instead letting user to scroll all the way up and down, is there any way to set the textblock (or other alternative control) auto paging (left and right), so the text would fill up the screen, then scroll right for the next page? tks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default controls which provide this and I'm not aware of any 3rd party offering such a control either.

The convention on Windows Phone and most mobile platforms is to have vertical scrolling for text. The exception to this is "books" where the paging metaphor is still used. But this is for more text than just "a long paragraph".
If you do build a control to provide the experience you're after then I strongly recommend performing careful user testing around the users expectations and experience around using it.

Comment: tks for the reply, actually the paragraph i meant is more like multiple long paragraph, say it's over 10k words, so scrolling up and down doesn't do much good, a book-like UI will be much better. any ideas?